# Remove line number before for statement in algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, algpseudocode

I am trying to remove the number before the `for loop` in the below algorithm. I would like to continue using the packages I am using, but have only found potential answers for `algorithm2e`. Is it possible to stop the algorithm from numbering the `for` statement?

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys,lineno,noend]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{amsfonts, bm, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}



\begin{algorithm}[!htp]
\caption{This is the algorithm 
}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require $\mathbf{X}$\\

Get initial information;\\

$\begin{aligned}
y = mx + b,
\end{aligned}$

\For{$i \gets 1 \text{ to } \vert k \vert$}{


do something

\EndFor}\\
get results

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily intervene and remove the line number printing algorithm when setting a `\For` and `\EndFor`. In the code below, `\NoLNFor` and `\NoLNEndFor` do just that using the following steps:

- Copy the current version of `\alglinenumber` (used to print the line number)
- Remove functionality of `\alglinenumber`
- Set `\For`/`\EndFor` as usual
- Step the line counter back one
- Restore `\alglinenumber`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\oldalglinenumber}{}% Dummy storage macro
\NewDocumentCommand{\NoLNFor}{ m }{%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\oldalglinenumber}{\alglinenumber}% Copy current version of line number printing macro
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\alglinenumber}{ m }{}% Turn \alglinenumber into a no-op
  \For{#1}% Print regular for command
  \addtocounter{ALG@line}{-1}% Step line counter back
  \RenewCommandCopy{\alglinenumber}{\oldalglinenumber}% Restore line number printing macro
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\NoLNEndFor}{}{%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\oldalglinenumber}{\alglinenumber}% Copy current version of line number printing macro
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\alglinenumber}{ m }{}% Turn \alglinenumber into a no-op
  \EndFor% Print regular end for command
  \addtocounter{ALG@line}{-1}% Step line counter back
  \RenewCommandCopy{\alglinenumber}{\oldalglinenumber}% Restore line number printing macro
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{This is the algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require $\mathbf{X}$
    \State Get initial information;
    \State $y = mx + b$,
    \NoLNFor{$i \gets 1 \textup{ to } \vert k \vert$}
      \State do something
    \NoLNEndFor
    \State get results
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

You'll note that I updated your code as well to conform to the syntax provided by [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). That is, don't use `\\`, but `\State`. Similarly, `$\begin{aligned} <math> \end{aligned}$` is more conveniently written as `$<math>$` when there's no alignment involved.